# Oracle - Remove specific space from string

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

we have some unformatted data which has been passed to us and need to convert it to minutes:

```
2hr
2hr 30min
3 hours
3 hr
3 hrs
3hr
3hrs
4 hours
4 hrs
4 hrs 10 mins
6 hrs
```

What I want to do is remove the first space from string, which will result in:

```
2hr
2hr 30min
3hours
3hr
3hrs
3hr
3hrs
4hours
4hrs
4hrs 10 mins
6hrs
```

Then, I can take the first "word" and convert it to minutes by removing everything not numeric and multiplying it by 60.  After, I can take every after the first word and add it to that result.   But I need to remove just the first space.

Am thinking REGEXP_REPLACE, but not sure how to work with only the first space.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to get rid of the spaces. You can find digits that are followed by zero-or-more spaces and then either `h` or `m` for hours and minutes.

```sql
SELECT duration,
       COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(duration, '(\d+)\s*h', 1, 1, 'i', 1)), 0) * 60
       + COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(duration, '(\d+)\s*m', 1, 1, 'i', 1)), 0)
         AS minutes
FROM   table_name;
```

or for decimal hours and minutes:

```sql
SELECT duration,
       COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(duration, '(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)\s*h', 1, 1, 'i', 1)), 0) * 60
       + COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(duration, '(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)\s*m', 1, 1, 'i', 1)), 0)
         AS minutes
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (duration) AS
SELECT '2hr' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2hr 30min' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3 hours' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3 hr' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3 hrs' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3hr' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3hrs' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4 hours' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4 hrs' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4 hrs 10 mins' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '6 hrs' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1.5 hrs' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '.25 hrs' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1.1m' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DURATION | MINUTES |
| --- | --- |
| 2hr | 120 |
| 2hr 30min | 150 |
| 3 hours | 180 |
| 3 hr | 180 |
| 3 hrs | 180 |
| 3hr | 180 |
| 3hrs | 180 |
| 4 hours | 240 |
| 4 hrs | 240 |
| 4 hrs 10 mins | 250 |
| 6 hrs | 360 |
| 1.5 hrs | 90 |
| .25 hrs | 15 |
| 1.1m | 1.1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2V3yZCqO)

Comment: Very interesting.   Did notice that some values were like this:  1.5hrs, and it converted that to 300 minutes, when it should be 90........

Comment: @LandonStatis That is not in your sample data. You can change the regular expression to `(\d+\.?\d*)\s*h` (and similar for minutes if you have fractional minutes) and it should handle decimals. If you get `.5hrs` (with no leading integer part) then use ``(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)\s*h`.

Comment: Awesome.   Many thanks!